# dealing with empty elements in lapply()

Tags: r, dataframe, lapply

it might be a rather beginner level question. lapply() is useful in applying a specific function on each component of a list. However, when I deal with data periodically generated by the data base, it happens sometimes, that one or more elements in the list is empty, while all other components of the same class are, let's say, data frames.

When I use lapply() to deal with the whole list, error occurs when it is the turn for the empty elements, because somehow the dimension or length or class don't fit. What I do in this case is using if/else loop, but I guess there must be a neat and smart way to tackle this problem.

Here is a example:

```
FTSR.site.app <- lapply(sortier.d.f, function(x) {
  if(length(x) != 1){
    FTSR <- as.numeric(get.FTSR(x))
    }else FTSR <- 0})
```

sortier.d.f is a list consisting of dataframes with numerous rows and columns. If an empty element among them is present, which means no data is generated there, it will not get alone with the get.FTSR function (I wrote for a particular calculation), because the latter can only process data frames. The length of this empty element will be 1, I guess because it still exists as a 0 or a FALSE. Otherwise without such empty elements I can simply use

```
FTSR.site.app <- lapply(sortier.d.f, get.FTSR(x))
```

Would you please suggest a better solution for the problem with empty elements in such a case?

A simpler dummy example here:

```
test.A <- data.frame(name <- c("Michael", "John", "Mary"), 
                     mathematik <- c(85, 72, 90), physics <- c(67, 82, 94))
test.B <- vector(length = 0, mode = "numeric")
test.L <- list(test.A, test.B)


sum.mean.calc <- function(test){
  test$total <- apply(test[,2:3], MARGIN = 1, sum)
  test$mean <- apply(test[,2:3], MARGIN = 1, mean)
  return(test)
}


test.L <- lapply(test.L, sum.mean.calc)

test.L <- lapply(test.L, function(x){
  if(length(x) != 0){
    x <- sum.mean.calc(x)
  }else x <- 0 
  return(x)
})
```

To first attemp to use lapply failed, because test.B is a 1-Dim vector with 0, so it can't be processed by function sum.mean.calc, so in the second attempt I have to use the extra loop

```
if(length(x) != 0){ 
...
}else x <- 0
```

to process all components in the list test.L, and that can be annoying when I want to use lapply a number of times on that list.

Comment: Please provide a reproducible self contained minimal example including code and all inputs to illustrate the question.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I just added an example.